# Define Apple ID Settings - red bubble, can't access with correct user/password

Tags: icloud, apple-id, password

Sometime ago I started receiving a notification on my Mac Mini M1 (macOS Ventura 13.1). After clicking it, it opens up the Settings app in macOS, and there it shows a red bubble on the "Define Apple ID Settings"

[image]

I try to write my Apple ID and password, but after doing it and clicking in "OK", it seems nothing happens, except that the red bubble dissapears and the number "1" inside it just stays there in a blue background.

I can use my Mac like always and I can access my Apple ID or iCloud through the browser for example, but I'm a bit confused by this behaviour. What can be the problem here?

[image]